I want to to count the maximum amount of times a value appears in a row in excel
Would any one be able to help.
I want to count the max amount of times a number appears in a row consecutively.
Eg. 1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0

So the question would be...
What is the most amount of times 1 appears in a row.
And the answer would be 4.
I have tried a couple of diffrent countif formulas but I just can't get it to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
=AND(A1=1,B1=1)+COUNTIFS(A1:W1,0,B1:X1,1,C1:Y1,1)


=(26-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(0,A1:Y1),"011","")))/3

Both of these some one previously posted but they only count a specific pattern eg. 001. I have tried manipulating them, but I just can't get it to work.

Max Consecutive Occurrences of a Value in a Row
Single Value and Row
=MAX(SCAN(0,A1:H1,LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r=1,rr+1,0))))


Multiple Values and Rows
=LET(data,A2:N21,
    MaxC,LAMBDA(data,crit,MAX(SCAN(0,data,
        LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r=crit,rr+1,0))))),
    h,SORT(UNIQUE(TOROW(data,3),1),,,1),
    d,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(data),COLUMNS(h),LAMBDA(r,c,
        MaxC(CHOOSEROWS(data,r),INDEX(h,c)))),
    VSTACK(h,d))





Hi thank you for the answer, in the above example =MAX(SCAN(0,A1:H1,LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r=1,rr+1,0)))) when r=1 I can change this to work with any number eg r=2 r=3 amd so on and it works well thank you, I cant seem to to get it to work if I change it to a phrase or a single letter thank you for your time @VBasic2008

You have to put the phrase in double quotes e.g. r="A" or you could enter it into a cell and refer to it with e.g. r=P2.

Note that you can use a slightly modified version of this formula, a so called LAMBDA formula, to create your own function. In the Name Manager, input a name e.g. MaxC and below, in the RefersTo box, enter the following formula: =LAMBDA(data,crit,MAX(SCAN(0,data(LAMBDA(rr,r,IF(r=crit,rr+1,0))))). Then you can utilize this function anywhere in your workbook e.g. by using =MaxC(A1:H1,1).

Thanks you I shown have know better with the "*" that was silly first thing in the morning ill put it down to. and thank you for the idea of Name manager I have not come across this before it seems like a time saver

By using SCAN function - Microsoft Support to get a running count of consecutive ones:
    item, 1,
    max_in_row, LAMBDA(row_,
        MAX(SCAN(0, row_, LAMBDA(acc, cur, (cur = item) * (acc + (cur = item)))))
    ),
    BYROW(A1:N5, max_in_row)
)



Inspired by VBasic2008's suggestion to add named function

define max_in_row as

=LAMBDA(row_, criteria,
    MAX(SCAN(0, row_, LAMBDA(acc, cur, criteria(cur) * (acc + 1))))
)


then use anywhere, for example in this case:

=BYROW(A1:N5, LAMBDA(r, max_in_row(r, LAMBDA(item, item = 1))))



You could try using the following formula:


=MAX(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(A1:N1),0,,1)))



Let’s say your row is in cells A1:Z1. To count how many times each unique value appears, use this formula:
=MAX(COUNTIF(A1:Z1, A1:Z1))

please note "max amount of times a ... appears in a row consecutively"

For single row:
=MAX(SCAN(0, N(MAX(A1:N1)=A1:N1), LAMBDA(a,v, IF(v=0, a*0, a+v))))

For multiple rows:
=BYROW(
    A1:N10,
    LAMBDA(r, MAX(SCAN(0, N(MAX(r) = r), LAMBDA(a,v, IF(v = 0, a * 0, a + v)))))
)


